# Как убедиться в получении ответа клиентом на сервере? Java HttpServlet

Tags: java, servlet

В моей системе клиент обращается к серверу, сервер создаёт заказ и фиксирует его в БД. Но из-за плохого интернет соединения запрос уходит, сервер создаёт заказ, а на клиенте происходит `timeout` запроса и клиент не получает `uid` заказа. Таким образом фактически заказ создан, а клиент об этом не знает и может создавать новые заказы.

Я так понимаю, что на стороне сервера стоит убедиться в том, что клиент получил `uid` заказа. Как это можно сделать?

Клиент Android приложение.
Сервер на Java располагается на Google Cloud Platform с помощью `AppEngine`. Запросы обрабатываются с помощью `HttpServlet`.

Comment: а клиент об этом не знает и может создавать новые заказы ... Как вариант - перед созданием нового заказа, проверять нет ли необработанных старых , и если есть возвращать какой-то респонс, который указывал бы на это.

Comment: Я думал об этом. Можно даже вернуть UID того заказа, который был создан, но это костыль все же. Правильнее удостовериться в том, что клиент получил UID и только тогда в БД запись делать. Это, конечно тоже упрощенный вариант, так как могут быть ошибки на сервере при создании заказа, но я в своей простенькой системе считаю, что сервер "не может ошибиться".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Я так понимаю, что на стороне сервера стоит убедиться в том, что клиент получил uid заказа. Как это можно сделать?

Это можно сделать следующим образом: вы отправляете `uid` запроса на сервер другому сервлету. Он его проверяет и отправляет клиенту. Если клиент не получает ответа от сервера значит сервер не убедился в том что ему отправили `uid` поэтому нужно посыалать его периодически через определенный интервал.

Comment: Не понимаю зачем слать uid заказа другому сервлету, если клиент не сможет подтвердить его получение. Мне кажется нужно организовать общение сервлета с клиентом типа: создай заказ, держи uid, я получил uid, хорошо записываю данные в bd. Но понять не могу как именно(

Comment: Подтвердить должен сервер а не клиент, если я правильно понял твой вопрос "на стороне сервера стоит убедиться в том, что клиент получил uid заказа". я не могу сказать что тебе кажется, это известно только тебе и как ты будешь это реализовывать надо было написать в вопросе.

Comment: Сейчас перечитал ваш ответ. То есть вы предлагаете запрашивать uid снова и снова, пока он не будет получен клиентом, а потом делать запрос на сервер с просьбой загрузить данные заказа для этого uid. Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: В принципе мне это подойдёт. Хотя я решил свою проблему немного иначе, неправильно скорее всего. Увеличил таймаут у клиента. Из-за того что происходила инициализация подключения к бд, первый запрос проходил за 12 секунд, поэтому срабатывал таймаут у клиента и он не получал uid заказа от сервера, который приходил позже. Но в случае обрыва соединения с сетью у клиента после отправки запроса, на сервере создастся заказ, а клиент uid не получит. Для диплома я и таймаутом обойдусь, но самому все же интересно как решаются такие проблемы правильно. С сокетами было проще... Эх...

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно на стороне сервера городить транзакцию с БД, транзакция открывается в момент первичного обращения (размещения заказа), создаете заказ и uid заказа отправляете клиенту. Клиент получает его и отправляет обратно что-то типа: *да, все получил*, при получении подтверждения вы закрываете транзакцию на сервере (`commit()`), иначе откатываете назад транзакцию (`rollback()`)

Как то так.

**Update**

Транзакция это конечно же механизм в первую очередь про ДБ, но не всегда (это так к слову).

Если у вас БД Firebase, то там реализован механизм транзакцию - [см. мануал](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) - см. вкладку Android, там даже разобран случай со слушателем (подтверждение транзакции если срабатывает слушатель)

Comment: Спасибо большое, а можно немного более конкретно про транзакцию. Я ответ возвращаю банальным resp.getWriter().println("response"). Не подскажите какой класс отвечает за эти транзакции? Где "копать"?

Comment: а где же все это время хранить транзакцию? учитывая что в последнем запросе **да, все получил** будет новый поток создан.

Comment: @АнтонКовальчук транзакции относятся к sql.

Comment: Ну, бд на FireBase, так что тут должны быть какие-то свои транзакты не относящиеся к sql. Эх...

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не знаю как ожидать "да, все получил" в текущую сессию, а не в новую.

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Comment: Запросил в гугле **Response Update Java Servlet**, но все равно что-то не то выдает. Может дадите ссылочку или какой-нибудь фрагмент кода для изучения. Это очень поможет.